# How can I make an emulated game run faster?

Tags: emulation, nintendo-gamecube

On my MacBook Pro (2.9 GHz i7) I want to play a legal emulated copy of Pokémon Colosseum. I would like to be able to speed play by having the game run faster than normal. I already have perfect frame rate and graphics but I want the actual game to run faster. Has anyone heard of this happening?

Comment: On GBA emulator there is a fast forward button, "Tab" iirc. So it should be one on Gamecube emulator, too. If it's possible to know the name of the emulator you're using it could help us to answer you.

Comment: Game physics? The best an emulator can do is speed up the entire game; it can't modify only parts of it. What emulator you're using will also play a part in how to answer this.

Comment: Fast forward buttons are a feature in certain emulators. I'm sure if you said which emulator you were using, someone would be able to tell you if it has that feature and how to use it.

Comment: **tgearhart**, this may be better under [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), unless you can clarify what emulator you are/will be using!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the Dolphin emulator version 5.0+, there are 2 options.

1. You can hold down the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key as a hotkey to speed up the emulation (as mentioned by @HugoZink).

   - You can change this hotkey (and more) under Options > Hotkey Settings.
2. If the <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work, then

   - Go to your main Dolphin Emulator window
   - Click Config
   - Change `Speed Limit` from `100%` to `Unlimited` or to the desired game speed.

     - Example: `200%` is twice the normal speed

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the [Dolphin emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org/).

You can hold down the `TAB` key to significantly speed up emulation.

You can change this hotkey (and more) under Options-Hotkey Settings.